# Connect to a network using only keyboard

Tags: networking, keyboard, internet

My mouse does not work right now, but still I would like to connect to the Internet. Normally I would click the network icon and choose the network, but how to get there without mouse?

I can go to "network connections" and modify the existing connections using the keyboard, but I cannot actually say that I want to connect to one of the connections there.

Maybe there is a shell command? I have 12.04 (unity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the menu, then navigate to NetworkManager icon using the arrow keys.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But one has to make sure that some application is opened which actually has a menu

Comment: The actual shortcut to open the menu is Alt+F10. It works even if there's no application opened.